# Is it possible to send SMS messages via Linux command-line?

Tags: command-line, sms, messaging

I need to send text messages to a specific phone number via Linux command-line. I've searched for a method to do so, but most are outdated, or seem like scams.

Is something like this still possible, and if so, what is the best/cheapest way to go about doing it?

Comment: you can send an email to the number, like `mail -s "out of space" 8887776541@messaging.sprintpcs.com <<< "$more_msg_var"`, but you'll have to find the correct domain for each carrier for each telephone number. Not sure if my sample domain is correct. I don't have access to former employers code. You may also have to experiment w your `mail` client to eliminate extra header type data leaking thru. AND requests like this are really off-topic for S.O. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before asking more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send SMS by running a Python script in Linux Command-line.

I have included here the python code for the script.

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

email = "Your Email"
pas = "Your Pass"

sms_gateway = 'number@tmomail.net'
# The server we use to send emails in our case it will be gmail but every email provider has a different smtp 
# and port is also provided by the email provider.
smtp = "smtp.gmail.com" 
port = 587
# This will start our email server
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp,port)
# Starting the server
server.starttls()
# Now we need to login
server.login(email,pas)

# Now we use the MIME module to structure our message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email
msg['To'] = sms_gateway
# Make sure you add a new line in the subject
msg['Subject'] = "You can insert anything\n"
# Make sure you also add new lines to your body
body = "You can insert message here\n"
# and then attach that body furthermore you can also send html content.
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

sms = msg.as_string()

server.sendmail(email,sms_gateway,sms)

# lastly quit the server
server.quit()
```

**But for this you need the SMS gateway of your carrier.**

For details plz have a look : [Link](https://dev.to/mraza007/sending-sms-using-python-jkd)